# Some upload file size issue on Android

Tags: android, file-upload, upload

I tried to upload File to samba.
Because the limit buffer only about 16mb on Android, so I split to 10mb.
Below is my upload code:

```
try {
    int TempLength = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

    SmbFile file = new SmbFile(url, auth);
    SmbFileOutputStream out = new SmbFileOutputStream(file);

    File LocalFile = new File("filepath");

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(LocalFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[TempLength];

    int length = -1;
    while((length = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer);
        out.flush();
    }
    out.close();
    fis.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I try upload file.
It can upload success, but the file size will error.
For example, if I upload a 15mb file, the file size of uploaded will show 20mb.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `out.write(buffer, 0, length);`